# Missing model properties in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have 3 models:

```
export class Period {
    lifeYears: number;
    lifeDevelopment: number;
}

export class PairYearQuantity {
    id: number;
    year: number;
    quantity: number;
}

export class MarketingPhase {
    status: string;
    period: Period;
    investments: PairYearQuantity[];
    costs: PairYearQuantity[];
}
```

I create an object as the following one:

```
const marketingPhase: MarketingPhase = {
    status: 'empty',
    period: {
        lifeYears: 3,
        lifeDevelopment: 2
    },
    investments: [
        {
            id: 1,
            year: 2018,
            quantity: 15
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            year: 2019,
            quantity: 8
        }
    ],
    costs: [
        {
            id: 7,
            year: 2018,
            quantity: 21
        },
        {
            id: 8,
            year: 2019,
            quantity: 13
        }
    ]
};
```

If I print the object in the console, the "id" property is missing and the value of "quantity" is null. It seems the PairYearQuantity model is not working well.

```
console.log(marketingPhase);
```

This is the result:

```
{
    status: 'empty',
    period: {
        lifeYears: 3,
        lifeDevelopment: 2
    },
    investments: [
        {
            year: 2018,
            quantity: null
        },
        {
            year: 2019,
            quantity: null
        }
    ],
    costs: [
        {
            year: 2018,
            quantity: null
        },
        {
            year: 2019,
            quantity: null
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I print for example `console.log(marketingPhase.investments[0].quantity);` I get `15`

Any idea what is this happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you modify `marketingPhase` somewhere? I check and it work. See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4vo5u5d/8021/)

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem with your models since they are just typescript classes. Can you provide some more details of your code? Maybe a plunker or a fiddle.